# Mass cell convert on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a really big spreadsheet in google docs. I have a collumn with time in UTC format. For instance `(2013, 10, 14, 12, 17) for 14 Oct 2013, 12:17 am`

I want to change it to ISO 8601. I have started to change them one by one, but the data is huge. Is there any other way to do it automatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn `(2013, 10, 14, 12, 17)` (assumed in A1) into a more conventional format:

```
=SPLIT(mid(A1,2,len(A1)-2),",")
```

to populate B1:F1 then:

```
=date(B1,C1,D1)+(E1+F1/60)/24
```

to convert to a date time index recognised by Google Sheets. The result might be formatted:

`dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm AM/PM`

to show: `14 Oct 2013, 12:17 PM`

or formatted otherwise by choice (ISO 8601 does not require a unique format).

This does not attempt to address any strange convention for the likes of 12:17 (ie treats that as 17 minutes after noon, not after midnight) nor any time difference due to location.